# When i reloading the page state.params are coming null

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-routing in my application and its working very nice but now I am showing content on a page according to the $state.params and when i come from an other link on that page then state.params are coming as our requirement but when i reload this page $state.params are coming null.

Routing:

```
intakeApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/intake');
$stateProvider.state('data', {
url: '/data',
controller: 'dataController',
templateUrl: 'data.html',
}).state('data.media', {
url: '?matterId',
templateUrl: 'media.html'
})
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Links to open pages:
Link to open main page:

```
<a ui-sref="data" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">Data</a
```

Link to open the content on main page:

```
function onClickRow(matterId) {
$state.go('data.media', { matterId: matterId }, { redirect: true });
}
```

Controller:

```
intakeApp.controller('dataController', ['$http', '$scope', 'intakeAppFactory', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', '$uibModal', '$filter', '$timeout', '$compile', '$state', '$stateParams', function PostController($http, $scope, intakeAppFactory, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $uibModal, $filter, $timeout, $compile, $state, $stateParams) {
$scope.state = $state.current;
$scope.params = $state.params;
if (($scope.params.matterId == undefined) && ($scope.params.mediaId == undefined)) {
$scope.showMatterTable();
}
if (($scope.params.matterId != undefined) && ($scope.params.mediaId == undefined)) {
$scope.showMediaTable();
}
if (($scope.params.matterId != undefined) && ($scope.params.mediaId != undefined)) {
$scope.showDatasetTable();
}
```

Main URL:
http://localhost:62814/data
Content Page Url In Main Page:
http://localhost:62814/data?matterId=000001-000001